# ASP.NET: Check Value of Database and preform if

Tags: asp.net, database

I have a 1 row table in my database. The row is called "Active", and its value is either 1(for active) or 2(for inactive)

I am wanting to check the database, and if the site is active, set the text of a label to "Site is currently Active" and if said field is "0", set the text of a label to "Site Is currently Inactive"

I know ti seems so basic, but I am stumped.I've tried repeaters, but I have no idea how to manipulate it for this type of situation

Comment: what is your database? sql server? oracle? mysql? ms access?

Comment: I am Using ASP.net.. The repeater gets the vlaue correctly(example: IT is outputting either 1 or 2).

Comment: usually, 0 is false/inactive and non-zero is true/active. also, you won't need to use repeater.

Answer (score 0):

Kept troubleshooting... This is finally working

```
Private Sub Repeater1_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles Repeater1.ItemDataBound
    Dim MyLabel As Label = e.Item.FindControl("SiteStatus")

    If MyLabel.Text = "1" Then
        MyLabel.Text = "SITE IS CURRENTLY ACTIVE"
        MyLabel.CssClass = "Green"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this in a formview control:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"
    Text='<%#Convert.ToBoolean( Eval("Active"))?"Site Is currently Inactive":"Site Is currently Active"%>'
    ></asp:TextBox>
```

OR

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"
    Text='<%# Eval("Active").ToString().Equals("True")?"Site Is currently Inactive":"Site Is currently Active"%>'
    ></asp:TextBox>
```